# HttpHandler not retaining filenames on download

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, httphandler

I am using an HttpHandler to serve documents within my ASP.NET web application. I can get it to work just fine with one issue which I can't quite figure out -- the filename isn't retained.

For example, if I am trying to serve a document called "New Patient Information Form.docx" and my handler is called "GetDocument.ashx" the file is downloaded as "GetDocument.docx" and "GetDocument(1).docx", "GetDocument(2).docx" etc. each time I download the file.

I want to use a handler instead of linking to the files directly for security reasons. I'm keeping the actual documents in the App_Data folder so they can't be browsed to directly.

Here's the code I'm using. I've switched the content disposition between "attachment" and "inline" but neither seem to have any affect on correcting this problem.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["ID"], out var id))
        throw new Exception($"Invalid DocumentID value ({id}).");

    var document = DocumentsHelper.GetByID(id);

    if (document == null)
        throw new Exception($"Invalid DocumentID value ({id}).");

    var documentDownloadDirectory = AppSettingsHelper.DocumentDownloadDirectory(); // "App_Data"

    var filePath = Path.Combine(documentDownloadDirectory, document.Filename);
    var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    // A content disposition of "attachment" will force a "Save or Open" dialog to appear when
    // navigating directly to this URL, and "inline" will just show open the file in the default viewer
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Dispositon", $"attachment; filename={document.Filename}");
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.ContentType = document.ContentType;
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
    context.Response.Flush();
}
```

The "document" object in my code is a class with properties relating to the document metadata (such as the filename, ID, etc.)

I am using both Chrome and Edge as the browser and both exhibit this same behavior. Is there a way for an HttpHandler to retain the original filename?

Update: I've created a new project with simplified code to try to narrow down the cause of the problem. Here's the code:

```
public class DownloadFile : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var fileName = "NoSpaces.docx";
        var basePath = context.Request.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
        var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Dispositon", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
        context.Response.Flush();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The filename does not contain spaces and the browser attempts to save the file as "DownloadFile.ashx" instead of "NoSpaces.docx". I am starting to wonder if the browsers are to blame as the last time I remember this working was back in May.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "the filename isn't retained"?  Retained by whom?  What do you expect to happen?  What are you seeing happen?

Comment: What does `document.Filename` evaluate to?

Comment: @Flydog57 - the downloaded file is named the same as the handler, not the name of the file. If I have a page with a bunch of links to different documents and the user attempts to download them they are all named the same.

Comment: @Griswald - document.Filename evaluates to whatever the file on disk is named

Comment: Sorry, this feels very familiar, but it's from an old job (so I can't look at the notes).  Have you played with Content-Type.  I'm pretty sure you will only be able to get this to work with a content-disposition of "attachment"

Comment: Have you looked at what's coming back to the browser using something like Fiddler?  The RFC referenced by @Griswald_911 says that the quotes are needed only if the filename has spaces (see section 5 of the RFC).

Comment: I also wonder if this could be an odd side effect of string interpolation

Comment: Also, could you post all the code related to your actual HttpHandler?

Comment: I have seen multiple threads suggesting that the browser is to blame, but just for completeness, try hardcoding the filename to see if it works. If it does try replacing `$"attachment; filename={fileName}");` with `string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));` in the simplified handler and see if that works. If not, you may be on your own here, unfortunately.

Comment: @Griswald_911 - Sorry it took so long to respond, I was on vacation. I tried that and it seems all browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, IE) all want to save the file as either DownloadFile.ascx or DownloadFile.docx. I know this worked some time ago and the fact that IE11 also does it makes me think this is code-related because as opposed to all four browsers changing the behavior as I don't think IE11 has been updated in some time. I'm stumped.

Comment: I wanted to share more of my findings with the four browsers I've tested with. The filenames are being set as follows: Chrome/Firefox: DowloadFile.ashx; Edge/IE11: DownloadFile.docx; To note, while Firefox saves the file as DownloadFile.ashx, it at least knows this is a Word document as I am presented with a dialog asking whether I want to open or save the file. I have also tried serving the file in the postback event handler of a WebForms page and get the same behavior, although the filename is the same as the page itself (.aspx extension for Chrome/Firefox and .docx extension for Edge/IE11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and this totally makes sense why all browsers behave the same way. I'm a bit surprised nobody else caught this but here it is:

I spelled "Content-Disposition" as "Content-Dispositon". It was ignoring the filename because the header name was incorrect.

I'm going to need to check all other handlers and make sure it's spelled correctly there too!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the filename inside double quotes like this:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Dispositon", $"attachment; filename=\"{document.Filename}\"");
```

Comment: [This](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-4.1) may be of use to the original poster.

Comment: The filenames may have spaces in them as well so I removed them but it makes no difference. I've used handlers like this for many years and don't see why this is happening now, I am almost certain this worked at one point.

Comment: Add context.Response.Clear() before adding the content disposition header

Comment: @moshin-mehmood - that doesn't work either. I don't believe the specification for content-disposition requires quotes around the filename, even if there are spaces.