# Downloading files in edge has page name not file name in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

In Chrome and Edge when I dowload a file, it is using the page name for the file name. So if the page is called download.aspx and the file is thereisanissue.docx.

The file name is download.docx. This doesn't happen in IE or FF. Please help.

Code (I send the strFilename and sql to the procedure)

```vb
 Dim dsFile As DataSet
 context.Current.Response.Clear()
        context.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
        If (byteArray Is Nothing) Then
            dsFile = GetFile(sql)
            byteArray = dsFile.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("FILE_BLOB")
        End If
 context.Current.Response.ContentType = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
 context.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=""" + strFileName + """")
  
context.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length - 1)

context.Current.Response.Flush()
            context.Current.Response.End()
```

Comment: Where is `strFileName` set?

Comment: It is passed in, its just a string, the name of the file ie stack.docx

Comment: Have you added breakpoint to debug the code in Chrome and Edge? What result do you get in this line `context.Current.Response.AddHeader(...)`? I don't know why there're so many double quotes in it, you can try with this `context.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName + ".docx")` to see if it works. Besides, I find a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714522/httphandler-not-retaining-filenames-on-download), maybe you have the same issue about setting the header wrong in somewhere.

Comment: Yes I tried that...the header reads correct: Headers {Content-Disposition=inline%3battachment%3b+filename%3d%22Class+Schedule.docx%22} but it still comes the page name Download.aspx instead of Class Schedule.docx

Comment: ok got it working if you add context.Current.Response.BufferOutput = True it retains the file name. Just looked backed to basics and tried all combo's for it to work. Also those double quotes are there so in case you have a file name with spaces in FF it will download this works.pdf, if not it will download this.pdf. The spaces cut of the file name. Thanks for your help.

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. I suggest that you post the solution for this issue and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and you'll have to change `Content-Disposition` from `inline` to `attachment`. Also remove the quotes in `filename`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFileName)
```

`inline` becomes handy when you want to display PDF files inmediately in the browser.